# Find duplicate point with same value

Tags: qgis

I have a shapefile containing civic numbers. For each number there are string values of street name and civic number. During the editing it happens that I make typing mistakes and at the end of the work I find some duplicate points, i.e. two or more civic numbers on the same street.

How can I easily find these duplicates in order to export them to another shape using QGIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe some SQL query using `group by` might help.
I Qgis, open DB Manager, select your shapefile and open an SQL window. Then in your query, try something along the lines:

```
select count(), civic_number, street from vector_file group by civic_number, street having count() > 1
```

Adjust your civic_number and street column name as needed. Also, adjust the vector_file name.

This query should list the duplicates you have in your shapefile.